# Should I use the present progressive tense or the present tense?

Tags: tense, present-continuous

> A lot of Chinese people are speaking Chinglish when they try to speak
>   English.

or

> A lot of Chinese people speak Chinglish when they try to speak
>   English.

When I was in high school years ago, I would definitely consider the latter to be the right one. Since the action, speaking Chinglish, is something people do on a regular basis, not at a specific point in time. However, after I'm exposed to a lot of youtube videos made by native English speakers, I somehow have a tendency to favor the first one. The first one seems to instantly come out of my mind. But I can't convince myself to accept the former when it comes to conscious reasoning. So is it technically incorrect to say the former?

Comment: Personally, I'd go with the latter as well if you're just making a generalization. However, you mention that you've watched a lot YouTube videos, so perhaps, because of the context, the former is OK as well.

Comment: I'd also go with the latter. But I'd like to refer you to a youtube video which might serve as a good indication as to where my sense for the present progressive tense comes from. 
https://youtu.be/_mw9-uk_QFk
Notice when the video is played till 34s, the speaker says "You're coming to a new country, ...". It seems that the present progressive tense is vastly used in casual speaking context. Tbh, I don't quite get it why he's saying "You're coming ...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *present-progressive* focuses attention on the act-in-progress. To use your example:

> If you listen to Chinese speakers who are trying to speak English,
>   you will hear that they are actually speaking Chinglish.

In the example above, the context licenses the present-progressive: "If you listen...you will hear..."

If you wish to make a statement of general truth, or make a statement emphasizing that something tends to be true or tends to happen, use the simple present:

> When Chinese speakers speak English, they often speak Chinglish.

P.S. The primary problem with the way these tenses are taught to non-native speakers is that the example sentences tend to be very simplified and bland, lacking precisely those contextual cues that would lead a native speaker to choose the one tense over the other.

Comment: How do you explain why the speaker says "You're coming to a new country, ..." when the video is played till 34s?
https://youtu.be/_mw9-uk_QFk

Comment: Having read what I've written above, how do you think I will explain it?

Comment: What you said and your examples make sense to me. I do feel that I need to be more exposed to how native speakers would say something in the authentic scenario.

Comment: We *often focus* on the act-in-progress when we *are trying* to present a real-world "concrete" or "dramatic" scenario to the listener, as distinct from a general truth:  "You're *coming* to a new country, and you want...."  (The explanation I've just given in this comment shows that very principle in action.)

Answer (score 0):

Just for your reference, here is a sentence from https://www.safaribooksonline.com/register/.

Notice the first comment:

> I’m really liking Safari for quick, focused learning.