# meaning of "come(s) out of my mind"

Tags: meaning

[From an ELL post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/116053/109190)

> However, after I'm exposed to a lot of youtube videos made by native English speakers, I somehow have a tendency to favor the first one. The first one seems to instantly **come out of my mind**. But I can't convince myself to accept the former when it comes to conscious reasoning.

[From another post](https://www.goodtherapy.org/blog/psychpedia/compulsive-lying)

> To make it seem less terrible, many of the lies that **come out of my mind**, are either so that I don’t have to explain when someone misunderstands me, or to make fun of myself.

I googled it but got neither definition nor explanation of the phrase. What's the meaning of "come out of my mind"?

---

[From Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=comes%20out%20of%20my%20mind%2Ccomes%20to%20mind%2Ccomes%20to%20my%20mind%2C%20come%20out%20of%20my%20mind&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccomes%20out%20of%20my%20mind%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomes%20to%20mind%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomes%20to%20my%20mind%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccome%20out%20of%20my%20mind%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccomes%20out%20of%20my%20mind%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomes%20to%20mind%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomes%20to%20my%20mind%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccome%20out%20of%20my%20mind%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

"comes out of my mind" gets 13,500 hits in Google Books.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the sources you quote are reliable - one is an ELL post, presumably from an English language learner, the other a comment on an article from a reader.

"Come *to* mind" is an idiomatic expression to describe the recall of thoughts, for example:

- When I think of great composers, Beethoven comes to mind.

In your first example, this idiom would fit perfectly and make sense in context, so I think that is just a mistake.

In your second example, although not idiomatic, it makes sense to say that thoughts "come out of" one's mind. However, I think a more idiomatic way to express that would be to say that thoughts come *from* one's mind.

Comment: Thank you. "fit perfectly ... so that is just a mistake" confuses me, would you please explain a little bit?